# Наибольшее из трёх целых чисел

Tags: python, python-3.x

Даны три целых числа в виде одной строки. Выведите наибольшее из этих трех чисел.
Входные данные:

```
7 14 106
```

Выходные данные:

```
106 - наибольшее
```

```
a = [] 
while True: 
    line = input("enter the number") 
    if line: 
        number = int(line) 
        a.append(number) 
    else: 
        break 
        max_number = max(a) 
        print(max_number)
```

Comment: a = []
while True:
    line = input("enter the number")
    if line:
        number = int(line)
        a.append(number)
    else:
        break
    max_number = max(a)
print(max_number)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
inp = "7 14 106"
print(max(map(int, inp.split())))
```

OR

```
inp = "7 14 106"
print(max(int(i) for i in inp.split()))
```

OR

```
inp = "7 14 106"
print(sorted(inp.split())[0])
```

Comment: Лучше просто `inp.split()`, без параметра будет разделение по пробелу, и, даже, сразу по нескольким подряд идущим

Comment: @gil9red ok....

Comment: Последний вариант - шутка? Сортировать строки (!) и взять из них первую (!) ?

Answer (score 5):

```
line = '7 14 106'
print(max(map(int, line.split()))) # 106
```

Answer (score 4):

```
line = input()
lst = line.split()
a = map(int, lst)
print(max(a), "- наибольшее")
```

---

*Объяснение:*

«Даны три целых числа **в виде одной строки**.»

Ваша программа игнорирует это и ожидает *любое количество* чисел, каждое в *отдельной строке.*

Значит, вместо вашего цикла используйте *только одно* применение функции `input()`, чтобы получить все 3 числа как одну строку, и затем ее разбить, например методом `.split()`:

```
line = input()
lst = line.split()
```

В переменной `lst` вы получите список, но не чисел, а строк, например такой:

```
["7", "14", "106"]
```

Теперь нужно еще перевести этот список строк на список чисел, например так:

```
a = [int(i) for i in lst]        # я сохраняю ваше имя для этого списка
```

или

```
a = map(int, lst)                # функция int применится к всякому элементу списка lst
```

Только затем примените функцию `max()`:

```
print(max(a), "- наибольшее")
```